# Python 3: How to compare two big files fastest?

Tags: python, json, hash, compare

In **"Big_file.txt**", I want to extract UIDs of **"User A"** which is not duplicated with UIDs in "**Small_file.txt**". I wrote the following code but it seems it will never stop running. So, how to speed up the process ? Thank you very much :)

```
import json

uid_available = []
linesB = []
for line in open('E:/Small_file.txt'):
    line = json.loads(line)
    linesB.append(hash(line['uid']))


for line in open('E:/Big_file.txt'):
    line = json.loads(line)
    if hash(line['uid']) not in linesB and line['user'] == 'User A':
        uid_available.append(line['uid'])
```

This is format of Big_file.txt (has 10 millions lines):

```
{'uid': 111, 'user': 'User A'}
{'uid': 222, 'user': 'User A'}
{'uid': 333, 'user': 'User A'}
{'uid': 444, 'user': 'User B'}
{'uid': 555, 'user': 'User C'}
{'uid': 666, 'user': 'User C'}
```

This is format of Small_file.txt (has few millions lines):

```
{'uid': 333, 'user': 'User A'}
{'uid': 444, 'user': 'User B'}
{'uid': 555, 'user': 'User C'}
```

The output I expect:

```
111
222
```

Comment: Use a dictionary, you'll significantly speed up the lookup performed by `not in`.

Comment: You can use `set` instead of a `list` to append values to skip checking if there is a duplicates.

Comment: @spectras and vishes_shell Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking up an item in a list takes `O(n)` time. If you use a `dict` or a `set` you can improve it to `O(1)`.

shortest modification you can do is :

```
linesB = []
for line in open('E:/Small_file.txt'):
    line = json.loads(line)
    linesB.append(hash(line['uid']))
linesB = set(linesB)
```

or to do it right

```
linesB = set()
for line in open('E:/Small_file.txt'):
    line = json.loads(line)
    linesB.add(hash(line['uid']))
```

Comment: Looking up an item in a `set` or a `dict` has an average complexity of _O(1)_. Check out [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). So your solution is even better than you thought :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I come from a c++ background and I make this mistake often.

Comment: You can certainly have the same in c++, in fact CPython interpreter is written in C. They just chose a different implementation for `dict`, using a hash table with [some tweaks](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c). Its main advantage is very fast lookup, but it obviously has to pay for it in other operations, most notably “very worst” worst cases when inserting.

Comment: Awesome ! Currently, My program run very fast :D